# limit selectable files by extensions rails and haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, haml

I'm using ruby on rails and haml, but I'm looking for a similar behavior to this:

```
input type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx">
```

but, with my code:

```
= f.file_field :document_file, class: 'margin-none'
```

I tried add it like a new parameter, but doesn't works.
Does Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=f.file_field(: document_file, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/doc,image/docx',class: 'margin-none')
```